What is a log and what is a trace?
The words "log" and "trace" are used regularly for describing information, written to an external file during execution of a program, but is there a fix and firm definition?
Some examples in my career:

When working for a telecom company, I learnt that a "trace" is a piece of information, written to an external file during the execution of a program. A "log", however, is a summary of a complete handling of some data (e.g. a telephone call enters the computer program, the program does some handling (connecting calling parties, playing announcements, invoicing, ...) and at the end, a log is created, which can also be written to an external file.
When working for another software company, working with the NLog library, it seems that logs are pieces of information, written to an external file during the execution of a program. As a complete handling is impossible to follow, it's not possible to make a summary of the entire handling of some data. The word trace does exist in the NLog library, as a log level.
While working in the telecom related field, I have dealt regularly with snippers. There information, caught at the gateways of a computer, seem to be called "traces".

So my question: is there a formal definition for the word "log" or "trace", or more general, is there any official worldwide website, explaining some software engineering related words?

I find the Wikipedia links to be quiet helpful:
Tracing, Logging.

@SvenTUM: I feel bad for not having thought of Wikipedia before, but one thing puzzles me: the difference between both seems to be that logging is more for "high"-level code while tracing would more be for "low"-level code. What's the exact definition between those two terms?

I always thought of "logging" as a general term and "tracing" as a specialization of "logging" -- a more specific kind of logging. I suspect that no matter how many articles or blog posts we point to, you won't find much consensus on day-to-day usage.

"is there a formal definition for the word "log" or "trace"?. Nope. At least none which has a clear, broad consensus (there are surely some sources on the internet which try to give a definition but no canonical one - and definitely not OpenTelemetry, I had never heard of it until today).

Most words in English Language are context-dependent; it's normal for the same word in different situations to have different semantic meanings.   When joining a new project/company you're likely to find your new co-workers using vocabulary whose meanings are understood in a different way by those people.  Part of being successful as a developer is adaptability in meeting other people in their use of vocabulary - You often just have to ask people within a particular context what they mean when they use a particular word then adapt your own use of language depending on your audience

@BenCottrell, part of being a successful developer, in many roles, besides (like you say) acquiring subtle meanings of terms used in a particular business, is actually designing a new terminology and/or rationalising vague terms. Effectively you're reconceiving the way you and other people talk and think, so that it is more precise, specific, or regular, and the terms then go into the computer code, and into the designs of the computer screens they interact with.

There's a summary in this article that I broadly agree with. It's a subjective classification.

Logs are human-readable flat text files that are used by developers to capture useful data. Logs messages occur at a single point in time (though not necessarily at every point in time)


Traces are also known as distributed traces. They traverse network, process, and security boundaries, to give you a holistic view of your system.

That is, "log" refers to the more adhoc style of recording what the software is doing for the user to debug, and "trace" refers to a more systematic, structured data capture organized around requests.

I think OpenTelemetry would be the most "authoritative" source. As it defines common concepts and standars for application observability.
It defines :

Logs
A log is a timestamped message emitted by services or other
components. Unlike traces, they aren’t necessarily associated with any
particular user request or transaction. You can find logs almost
everywhere in software. Logs have been heavily relied on in the past
by both developers and operators to help them understand system
behavior.


Distributed traces
A distributed trace, more commonly known as a trace, records the paths taken by requests (made by an application or end-user) as they propagate through multi-service architectures, like microservice and serverless applications.

What you describe is more specific to telecom industry or possibly specific system you had worked on. But OTEL is relatively new as a standartisation, so older systems are likely to use different definitions.

To me a way more common example of a trace is the stack trace.
Also logs do not have to be timestamped. Most log files are, you can't just log to log files though.

OpenTelemetry is a source. But I doubt it is anything near an "authoritative source".

I think Euphoric's answer sets a good baseline, however:
Logs
I think the definition of a log is missing a defining characteristic, specifically that the log as a whole (rather than the individual message) identifies the thread of execution.
Meaning that if you have an application/service deployed to a set of servers each of which have multiple processes, each of which have multiple threads. It is typically possible to filter the log to a specific server, specific process on that server and a specific thread within that process.
Once this filtering is applied, you are able to see what the thread is doing as a list of sequential steps.
Note: Depending upon the use case, the thread may be identified based on the request/transaction it is servicing rather than an explicit Thread-Id. Additionally logging onto the correct server and examining the correct file may be sufficient to filter down to the server and process you are looking for.
Trace
Euphoric gives a good definition of a "Distributed Trace".
However the term "Trace" can be used in many contexts, so per the OP's original question, I don't think a firm definition exists for a generic "Trace" without any qualifying context, some contexts might be:

A distributed trace.
A stack trace.
The act of tracing a bug.

The only commonality, I see in the various usages of the word "trace" is it usually refers to a context where someone has access to the source code and/or extremely detailed knowledge of the flow of execution of the software.

I imagine there's a distinction in telecoms between "logging" a call (as would be done for routine billing activity), and "tracing" a call (as would occur internally only for systemic reasons, or as a special effort for criminal investigation etc.).
In broader usage, a "log" also has the connotation of a recording activity performed specifically by human action, whereas a "trace" tends to imply the remnants of a physical activity which are caused or left behind incidentally.
In a typical computing context, I don't think there would be a basis to precisely distinguish the meanings of the words, except that if both are used in one context then "trace" should imply the generally more detailed data which is less meaningful or collected for less specific purposes than are "logs".
